# Get original size of video with Objective-C in OS X

Tags: objective-c, macos, video, osx-lion, avfoundation

What's the simplest way to get the original size (width & height) of a video with Objective-C in Mac OS X 10.7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming the movie is something readable by QuickTime -- and if it isn't you're probably out of luck anyway -- something like this should do the trick, I think:

```
QTMovie* movie = [QTMovie movieWithFile:movieFileName error:nil];
NSSize size = [(NSValue*)[movie attributeForKey:QTMovieNaturalSizeAttribute] sizeValue];
```

(NB: untested, no error checking, etc.)